# sklearn "balanced_accuracy_score" sample_weights not working

Tags: scikit-learn, accuracy, metric

I wanted a metric where I could weigh each class as I wish while measuring "total accuracy". `sklearn` seems to have this with `balanced_accuracy_score`. Irrespective of the sample_weight, I am getting the same "balanced accuracy". Why? what was the point of `sample_weights`?

```
from sklearn.metrics import balanced_accuracy_score

sample_weight = np.array([1 if i == 0 else 1000 for i in y])
balanced_accuracy_score(y,m.predict(xs),sample_weight=sample_weight)
```

Here are the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.balanced_accuracy_score.html#sklearn.metrics.balanced_accuracy_score).

Answer (score 3):

The point of `sample_weights` is to give weights to specific sample (e.g. by their importance or certainty); not to specific classes. 
Apparently, the "balanced accuracy" is ([from the user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#balanced-accuracy-score)):

> the macro-average of recall scores per class

So, since the score is averaged across classes - only the weights within class matters, not between classes... and your weights are the same within class, and change only across classes.

Explicitly (from the user guide again):

> $$\hat{w}_i = \frac{w_i}{\sum_j{1(y_j = y_i) w_j}}$$

i.e. the i-th sample is re-weighted by dividing its weight by the total weights of samples with the same label.

Now, if you want, you can just use the simple [accuracy score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html), and plug in weights as you see fit.

In the following example:

```
from sklearn.metrics import balanced_accuracy_score, accuracy_score

y_true = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
y_pred = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

some_sample_weights =[10, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
weights_by_class =[1 if y==1 else 1000 for y in y_true]

print('with some weights: {:.2f}'.format(balanced_accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=some_sample_weights)))
print('without weights: {:.2f}'.format(balanced_accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)))
print('with class weights in balanced accuracy score: {:.2f}'.format(balanced_accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=weights_by_class)))
print('with class weights in accuracy score: {:.5f}'.format(accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=weights_by_class)))

class_sizes = [sum((1 for y in y_true if y==x))/len(y_true) for x in (0,1)] 
weights_by_class_manually_balanced = [w/class_sizes[y] for w, y in zip(weights_by_class, y_true)]

print('with class weights in accuracy score (manually balanced): {:.5f}'.format(accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=weights_by_class_manually_balanced)))
```

you get:

```
with some weights: 0.58
without weights: 0.79
with class weights in balanced accuracy score: 0.79
with class weights in accuracy score: 0.75012
with class weights in accuracy score (manually balanced): 0.75008
```

As you can see:

- using class weights in the balanced accuracy score didn't matter; they just got adjusted back into class sizes.
- using class weights in the accuracy score is very close to 75% (3 of out of 4 the `0` labels are correctly classified), and re-adjusting the weights according to class sizes doesn't matter much (the accuracy is a bit less, because the `0` class is larger)

Comment: "It is the macro-average of recall scores per class or, equivalently, **raw accuracy where each sample is weighted according to the inverse prevalence of its true class.**". I don't get it, why you are saying then that weights within the class only are important. I can see it in your example, but I don't get why the "weights doesn't work" across classes. I was expecting (as this is for unbalanced datasets) that it would do a weighted average. And the only way to give input is by using `sample_weights`.

Comment: I added the explicit calculation (from the user guide) that shows explicitly why the weights don't work across classes. I think you might want to derive your own score (do the macro-average of recall scores as a weighted average, not average by class sizes); the balanced-accuracy-score isn't what you need. Maybe just take the accuracy score and divide your weights by the class weights?

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain how to use custom weights in accuracy score.